# Epsilon Tensor Changing Sign

Tags: tensor-calculus, conventions

I am trying to solve a commutator relation containing an epsilon tensor. The expression has the following form: $\epsilon_{3kj} \sigma_{j} x_{k}$.

Because of an other solution, this should be rewritten as: $\epsilon_{ij3} \sigma_{j} x_{I}$.

I am now having problems to find the sign change. These are the following steps that I made:

$\epsilon_{3kj} \sigma_{j} x_{k}$  = - $\epsilon_{k3j} \sigma_{j} x_{k}$ =  $\epsilon_{kj3} \sigma_{j} x_{k}$ = $\epsilon_{ij3} \sigma_{j} x_{i}$

Now my question is, is there also a sign change, when I change the indices of the $x_{k}$ to $x_{i}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\epsilon_{ijk}$ is a completely anti-symmetric tensor. Hence,
$$\epsilon_{3kj} \leftrightarrow -\epsilon_{k3j} \leftrightarrow \epsilon_{kj3}$$

Since $k, j$ are *dummy* indices, there won't be any sign change: $$\epsilon_{kj3} \sigma_{j}x_k = \epsilon_{ij3} \sigma_j x_i$$

Dummy indices will be summed over and it does not matter what letter you choose to represent it with.

Comment: Ah that's perfect! Thank you!